# Are there any 1D laser barcode scanners that work well with iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a scanner that works similarly to the [Microvision ROV](http://www.microvision.com/store/ROV-Scanner-with-Bluetooth-p-2.html) which has worked very well for me in the past when connected to a [Mac and Delicious Library](http://www.delicious-monster.com/).

[image: microvision rōv bluetooth scanner]

Is there anything comparable on the market for iOS bluetooth scanning?

Requirements are to be dedicated external hardware. I prefer battery powered, bluetooth and fast/rugged aspect of a 1D laser powered barcode scanner. Small is nice, but the [KoamTac](http://www.koamtac.com/) appear to be too fragile so I'd rather something built more like the micro vision or [symbol line of USB scanners](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/LS2208_US-EN) that are built more like tanks.

I don't need 2D scanning and am really looking for a laser to pick the exact line needed to read multiple barcodes and rapidly scan in low light situations. I'm hoping someone has actually used this hardware and can speak to the usability of any devices for industrial and/or high volume scanning (think 100 iMac that need inventory from Apple's barcodes sitting on a shipping dock).

What hardware can assist with this?

Comment: huh... why not use an app that uses the camera? why does it need to be an external hardware solution? I can't tell for sure it looks like Delicious Monster has an app called Delicious Scanner in the iOS app store.

Comment: Laser pointing lets me scan dozens of items in dark light one after the other. Also - I have labels with 5 or more barcodes, and getting the camera to pick them out is hard. It's trivial to control the above scanner and get just the right one of the 5 scanned - reducing the burden to filter and screen out the wrong bar codes. Good question @dwightk

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of the Socket CX2870-1409 Barcode Scanner?
https://www.barcodesinc.com/socket/part-cx2870-1409.htm#overview

The reviews are very decent across the board.

Comment: I don't know - have you used it or was that a google search or something you saw in use?

Comment: Did some digging on what were the more popular scanners for businesses that had major scale that supports the ios mobile operating system. This one came up often and looking at the reviews on this site I can see that most buyers prefer it